# Как ставить ударение в имени ДИОНИС?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно: ДиОнис или ДионИс? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В древнегреческом языке имя Дионис имеет ударение на 3 слог от конца: DiOnysos. Однако, русский язык допускает в таких случаях перенос ударения на последний слог. Иногда это даже становится нормой (katAlogos - каталОг). В случае с Дионисом допустимы оба варианта.

Answer (score 0):

В греческом языке ударения, как правило, ставятся на предпоследний слог. Следовательно ближе к оригиналу будет "ДиОнис".